# how to work with other developers using hg's defaut stable branch workflow

Tags: mercurial, workflow, branch, tortoisehg, branching-and-merging

I found an article talking about git's workflow [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), And tried to apply it to my own hg project, seems that it's kind of mess when I create a branch for each feature, cause in git, the branch could be deleted, and in hg, it can only be closed. so this will lead to a huge amount of closed branches in the repo, and that's what I don't want to see.

later, I googled another article which talks about a Hg workflow [here](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/05/mercurial-workflows-stable-default/) I tried it, and it seems good when I am the only developer of the project, but when I tried to add another developer, the history became a little complicated.

I tested this with three repos

```
1, Base
2, devA   ---> stands for developer A's repo
3, devB   ---> stands for developer B's repo
```

first I worked on devA, making changes on devA's `default` branch, and bugfix's on devA's `stable` branch. After that, I push devA to Base.

devA's graph:

[image: devA's graph]

in case the image broken, the text based graph is here:

```
@    summary:     Merge with stable
|\   tag:         tip
| |  parent:      4:d2973e149720
| |  parent:      5:3788143e99fc
| |  date:        Mon Jul 30 13:17:44 2012 +0800
| |  
| |
| o  changeset:   5:3788143e99fc
| |  branch:      stable
| |  parent:      3:4a955d01ea44
| |  date:        Mon Jul 30 13:17:19 2012 +0800
| |  summary:     fix a bug in featureA
| |
o |  changeset:   4:d2973e149720
| |  parent:      2:8e106fcfa9bf
| |  date:        Mon Jul 30 13:16:46 2012 +0800
| |  summary:     finish featureA advance
| |
| o  changeset:   3:4a955d01ea44
|/|  branch:      stable
| |  parent:      1:7b81b986d485
| |  parent:      2:8e106fcfa9bf
| |  date:        Mon Jul 30 13:16:01 2012 +0800
| |  summary:     Merge with default
| |
o |  changeset:   2:8e106fcfa9bf
| |  parent:      0:7d7dc422ec7c
| |  date:        Mon Jul 30 13:15:43 2012 +0800
| |  summary:     finish feature A
| |
| o  changeset:   1:7b81b986d485
|/   branch:      stable
|    date:        Mon Jul 30 13:14:49 2012 +0800
|    summary:     Create stable branch
|
o  changeset:   0:7d7dc422ec7c
   date:        Mon Jul 30 13:14:21 2012 +0800
   summary:     Init commit
```

and then I switched to devB, because I want to emulate a parallel work, so I did not pull from Base, instead I begin to work on devB's `default` branch, and do bugfix on devB's `stable` branch.

devB's graph is similar with devA's graph

Here comes the problem, when I try to push devB's changes to Base, it said there is a conflict, and I need to merge it locally, I pulled the changes and then my history graph in devB became kind of messy because I got devA's `default` and `stable` so in devB there is now two `default` branches and two `stable` branches.

what confused me is how real projects use this kind of workflow, mecurial's branch graph is [here](http://selenic.com/repo/hg/graph). It seems pretty clean, but how did they do this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't split repository into "developer branches", branch "feature branches" instead. Each branch should have reasonably small number of commits all devoted to implementation of particular feature. On each build/release, you select branches ready to be deployed and merge them to default.

Comment: but that will lead to a huge amount of branches which I can't delete, maybe it is a good way, but I'm confused of how `tortoishg` and `mercurial` uses the `default` `stable` branch workflow.

Comment: @shengy, They will become one with default on merge. Note how there's only line after change 6.

Comment: Umm... I can't understand what you mean, could you explain it more detail? or post an answer?

Comment: @shengy, when you done with branch and merge it somewhere else, likely to `default`, it doesn't become closed branch. On graph both lines just join into one and then continue as one line/branch.

Comment: but if I have 10 features and I should merge it 10 times, this is all ok, if I have a bug on feture 1 I have to update to feature 1 and fix the bug and merge it again, this will cause a huge amount of branches, and make the central repo's history graph more and more complex. I there any way I can push the merged local default branch only to server?

Comment: @shengy, merge just before release and forget about merged branch. Dedicate new branch to bugfix.

Comment: so are these feature-branchs pushed to the central repo?

Comment: *so are these feature-branchs pushed to the central repo?* **Yes.** Just close these branches to remove them from tools completion.

Answer (score 0):

The [latest hgflow](https://bitbucket.org/yujiewu/hgflow/wiki/Home) (0.9.5, not yet released officially, but it works great) actually allows you to completely delete a feature branch. Excerpt from its Wiki:

> Added --erase for the finish action. With this option, you erase (i.e., completely delete from the repository) the branch after it is successfully finished. The final effect is as if all changes in the branch were collapsed and then committed as a single changeset to the destination branch which the branch was merged to. Check out hg flow help @finish for a bit more detail.